# How to console.log to firefox console instead of terminal in addon-sdk from Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, output, firefox-addon-sdk

I've made a simple firefox addon following basic tutorials for addon-sdk. In the code I have some console.log outputs that I'd like to see under firefox console (f12>console) when I `cfx run` (like when using console.log from nodejs).

Calling firefox from terminal spawns output from various sources and it is hard to track my own.

Comment: Also, looks like console.log is ignored so I used console.error instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could workaround the problem by using ***`Browser Console`*** (***`Ctrl+Shift+J`***), and then filtering messages by some string - let's say "@@@", which you'd place in every message you log.

***`Browser Console`*** presents the same sorts of messages ***`Web Console`*** does, but it does so for:

- web content hosted by all browser tabs,
- the browser's own code,
- add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below steps :

1. Create an xpi file of your addon by running "cfx xpi".
2. Open a new firefox window and use hot key "Ctrl+Shift+j". This will open the browser console.
3. Click on "js" and then click on clear.
4. Drop the created xpi file in to this firefox window now and install it.
5. Now the browser console will contain only the logs of your addon.

   NOTE : If you feel it is a pain to create xpi file everytime, you can use [Extension Auto-Installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autoinstaller/) which will listen to a port for any update made in an addon. Refer "Developing without cfx run" section under this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started)

Comment: Drag and drop xpi didn't work for me in firefox 35.0 on arch linux

Comment: @Radivarig Try "File --> Open File" locate the .xpi file and open it.

Comment: It offers me only to install it but not to add to console for filtered output. Altho I auto-install my .xpi with your Auto-Installer (which works great, thanks!) then use console.error("@@@ msg").

Comment: ya you will have to install it and try to do operations which would print the logs. You will be able to see these logged messages under Browser Console(Ctrl + Shift + j)